# scss mixin with focus: mixin with focus not working

Tags: scss-mixins

*Update*: here is the full code: [codepen](https://codepen.io/devvue/pen/bGvqrrL)

I have below HTML: here is the full code

```
 <input id="id1" value="planner" type="checkbox" />
 <label for="id1">Name</label>
```

Before the label I want to insert an icon so I have the below the CSS file.

```
input[type=checkbox] + label:before { 
  @include custom_square; 
  content:'';
  display: inline-block;
}
```

my custom icon `mixin` is as below:

```
@mixin custom_square {
    width: 10px;
    height: 10px;
    border-radius:20%;
    border:1px solid #0069aa;
    margin-right:0.3rem;
    &:focus::after {
      border:1px solid #ffffff;
    }
  }
```

now when user focus the lable it does color change the css for it as below:

```
input[type=checkbox]:focus + label,
    input[type=radio]:focus + label {color: #fff;}
```

Also, I want to change the border color of the square to `white` on the focus of it, I have added `&:focus::after pseudo element in the mixin custom_square`  but it seems it is not working, any clue?

P.S: I don't want to use font-awesome icons, instead I will be creating my own icons and would be inserting that as shown above:

Comment: any help here please?